# Anyon statistics in a lattice Moore-Read state

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-order, quantum-hall-effect, anyons

I'm trying to understand [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.11222)<sup>1</sup>, in particular the remark after Eq. 26.

Let me rephrase the problem. According to the paper, one can write the Berry phase as
$$
\theta_B=i\oint_\Gamma\frac{1}{C}\frac{\partial C}{\partial w_k} \mathrm{d} w_k +c.c.=i\oint_\Gamma\frac{\partial \ln C}{\partial w_k} \mathrm{d} w_k +c.c.
$$
where $\Gamma$ is the closed path along which we move anyon $k$, whose position is given by a complex number $w_k=x_k+iy_k$ and $C$ is the normalization constant (I consider the simplest case of nondegenerate states, so I drop the index $\alpha$). Here, $C=\sqrt{\sum_{n}\Psi_{n}\bar{\Psi}_{n}}$ where $\Psi_{n}$ depend on $w_k$ and not $\bar{w}_k$ (the bar denotes complex conjugation). Likewise, $\bar{\Psi}_{n}$ depend on  $\bar{w}_k$ and not $w_k$. I'm fine with the derivation of the above equation. But now, according to the paper, if we show that $C$ is lattice-periodic in $w_k$, $\bar{w}_k$ (which they show numerically, see Fig. 4b), then $\theta_B$ phase is zero, and I do not understand why.

I know that the case considered in the paper is the lattice version of the situation considered in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.5194)<sup>2</sup>. In this case, the system is continuous, and thus instead of the periodicity they need to show that $C$ is a constant. And then it is fairly obvious to me that the phase is zero, since all the derivatives vanish. But I don't know how to extend it to the case when we have periodic $C$ instead of a constant.

In a naive interpretation of the lattice case, we can say that:
$$
\oint_\Gamma\frac{\partial \ln C}{\partial w_k} \mathrm{d} w_k=\ln C |_{end}-\ln C |_{start}
$$
which vanishes, because the start and the end of the path coincide. This reasoning would be correct in the case of real integrals, but I think it does not work for complex contour integrals.

Consider the following counterexample: just one basis state and one anyon (thus I drop the indices) with $\Psi=w$. Let us consider $\Gamma$ parametrized by $w=e^{it}$, so that $C=\sqrt{w \bar{w}}=1$ everywhere on the path. A constant is clearly periodic on the path, so according to the naive reasoning the integral should yield 0. But, calculating explicitly
$$
\oint_\Gamma\frac{1}{C}\frac{\partial C}{\partial w} \mathrm{d} w=
\oint_\Gamma\frac{1}{2C^2}\frac{\partial C^2}{\partial w} \mathrm{d} w=
\oint_\Gamma\frac{1}{2w \bar{w}}\frac{\partial w \bar{w}}{\partial w} \mathrm{d} w=
\oint_\Gamma\frac{1}{2w} \mathrm{d} w= \pi i
$$
which is not zero. So the periodicity within the path is not enough to guarantee the vanishing of the result. But the lattice periodicity is a stronger claim (a periodicity in two directions). However, I don't know how to use it to show that the phase vanishes.

Maybe this is a simple issue within the complex analysis. I am not very good in this subject, and all the books I have found focus on the holomorphic functions, while $C$ is clearly not holomorphic. If anyone can recommend a good book where these subjects are discussed, it would also be fine.

---

1. S. Manna, J. Wildeboer, G. Sierra & A. E. B. Nielsen, "Non-Abelian quasiholes in lattice Moore-Read states and parent Hamiltonians", *Phys. Rev. B* **98**, 165147 (2018), arXiv:1807.11222.
2. P. Bonderson, V. Gurarie & C. Nayak, "Plasma Analogy and Non-Abelian Statistics for Ising-type Quantum Hall States", *Phys. Rev. B* **83**, 075303 (2011), arXiv:1008.5194.